# Display JFreeChart with spring MVC ( No mapping found )

Tags: image, spring, jfreechart, url-mapping

I know that there is many similar post to this. But I didn't find any complete code of how to display JFreeChart to the `<img>` tag.

I'm displaying the image onload of the page.

**NOTE:** The URL this page is:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/student", method = RequestMethod.GET )
```

At the same page I'm trying to get the image onload with different URL mapping.  *( I don't if this is possible but the URL mapping I think where the error is )*

```
<div class="chart-image">
    <img src="../admin/student/getChart.do" class="img-rounded" />
</div>
```

The controller that render the chart is this:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath:^tutor$|^admin$}/student/getChart", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void displayChart( HttpServletResponse response )
{
    response.setContentType( "image/png" );
    try
    {
        JFreeChart chart = getChart();
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG( response.getOutputStream(), chart, 600, 400 );
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        // no logger yet
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this message from my console:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/ThesisProject/admin/student/getChart.do] in DispatcherServlet with
>   name 'ThesisProject'

I don't get it why does my `<img>` tag doesn't seems see the controller that suppose to render the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `.do` extension in your URL but not in your `@RequestMapping`, so change your mapping to include it:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath:^tutor$|^admin$}/student/getChart.do", method = RequestMethod.GET )
```

Or your could always remove the `.do` extension from the URL in the `<img>` tag, but it depends on how you are mapping the DispatcherServlet in `web.xml`  (ie. `*.do`)